# Shell BackButtonBehavior command binding not working in UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp, xamarin.shell

I am kind of new to Xamarin development. I tried to change the back button behavior with a binding command, but that didn't seem to work. This is the code for the view:

```
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior Command="{Binding GoBack}"/>
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

And this is the code for the view model:

```
public CreatePasswordVM()
{
    _goBack = new Command(GoBackButton);
}
private ICommand _goBack;
public ICommand GoBack
{
    get { return _goBack; }
}
public async void GoBackButton()
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../..");
}
```

When I pressed the back button, the method "GoBackButton" didn't call. I want to mention that on Android works.

Comment: BindingContext missing? Check [this discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/179742/backbuttonbehavior-in-shell-not-working). [Sample in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#back-button-behavior) didn't use mvvm btw.

Comment: No, BindingContext is not missing... Is there a problem that I used mvvm?

Comment: @himynameisgarch, I could reproduce your problem, the reason is BackButtonBehavior has not been  implemented for uwp platform. I have post the source code below, please have a look.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I saw it, I already made an issue on Xamarin Forms github! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shell BackButtonBehavior command binding not working in UWP

Derive from Xamarin Form source code. `BackButtonBehavior` has not implemented for UWP platform, we could find Android and IOS implementation [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ShellToolbarTracker.cs) and [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/ShellPageRendererTracker.cs). But for uwp there is not such tracker and there is not such value in the UWP [`ShellRenderer`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Shell/ShellRenderer.cs). For this scenario, we suggest your post new feature request in the [Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) github.